# All combination formula for columns AND rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that works in generating all combinations from the rows data. I also want to generate all combinations from the columns data, within the same formula. In other words, I'm correctly getting results of B2,C2 D2...B2, C3, D4...all combinations from 3 columns. I also want results included from rows, in other words B2,B3,B4....C2,C3,C4....D2, D3, D4......

Here's the formula I'm using, just unsure how to modify it to include row combinations.

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")))&" "&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(D2:D, D2:D<>""))))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Kindly share a dummy sheet with your input and desired output.